# Show Validation message after focus-out textbox or user typed fully

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am some validations messages:

```
<form name="dnaform" novalidate>
    <div style="padding-bottom:5px" ng-show="dnaform.uEmail.$pristine || dnaform.uEmail.$valid">Active directory account </div>
    <div style="padding-bottom:5px;" ng-show="dnaform.uEmail.$dirty && dnaform.uEmail.$error.required" class="help-block">Email is Required.</div>
    <div style="padding-bottom:5px;" ng-show="dnaform.uEmail.$error.email" class="help-block">Invalid Email.</div>
    <input type="email" name="uEmail" class="form-control txtBoxEdit type7N" ng-model="useremail" required>
</form>
```

The problem is that it will show validation message instantly the user types something in the email textbox, but I want to show the message when user typed fully email text or the focus of textbox out.

Comment: How about `ng-blur` over `input` element ?

Comment: @develper033 firt time it is working..but second time not working. could you make a fiddle ?

Comment: @SivaRajini, check the last version please.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$touched`:

```
<div style="padding-bottom:5px;" ng-if="dnaform.uEmail.$touched && dnaform.uEmail.$error.email" class="help-block">Invalid Email.</div>
```

From **docs**:

1. `ng-touched`: the control has been blurred, in other words, once the field is **touched** it will keep validating on other times, but since you don't want it, you should add it into your `<input>`:

```
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
```

*Snippet:*

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {

    })
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <form name="dnaform" novalidate>
    <div style="padding-bottom:5px" ng-show="dnaform.uEmail.$pristine || dnaform.uEmail.$valid">Active directory account </div>
    <div style="padding-bottom:5px;" ng-show="dnaform.uEmail.$dirty && dnaform.uEmail.$error.required" class="help-block">Email is Required.</div>
    <div style="padding-bottom:5px;" ng-if="dnaform.uEmail.$touched && dnaform.uEmail.$error.email" class="help-block">Invalid Email.</div>
    <input type="email" name="uEmail" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" class="form-control txtBoxEdit type7N" ng-model="useremail" required>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

For more check [**here**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms/#using-css-classes).

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Write some function to call when input blurs. Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh1cqdcw/)

```
$scope.blurred = function() {

    };
```

Call this function when input blurs

```
<input type="text" ng-blur="blurred(inputsData)" ng-model="inputsData">
```